# Selenium - How to check and increment dropdown value if it is already present?

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation

I am trying to automate an application using Selenium Webdriver (Java). My web application has an Add button. Once the add button is clicked, a dropdown will enabled. If it is clicked again, a second dropdown will be enabled. Each subsequent dropdown's ID would be page1, page2, page3.. and so on..

What I want to do is when I open the page, I need to find out if any dropdown is already present in the page, if yes, then select the next dropdown value, and then select a value from the dropdown.

This is my current code, where I am manually selecting each dropdown and selecting their respective values.:

```
driver.findElement(By.id("addPage")).click();
new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("page0"))).selectByVisibleText("ABCD");
driver.findElement(By.id("addPage")).click();
Thread.sleep(1000);
new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("page1"))).selectByVisibleText("CDEF");
driver.findElement(By.id("addPage")).click();
Thread.sleep(1000);
new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("page2"))).selectByVisibleText("EFGH");
driver.findElement(By.id("addContact")).click();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can locate any select element with `id` starting with `page`, get the `id` attribute value and click the dropdown with the next page. Sample implementation:

```
WebElement existingPage = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("select[id^=page]"));

String nextPageID = Integer.toString(Integer.parseInt(existingPage.getAttribute("id").replaceAll("\\D+", "")) + 1);
Select nextPage = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("page" + nextPageID)));
```

And, as @Iridann correctly pointed out, to check the presence, catch the `NoSuchElementException` exception:

```
try {
    WebElement existingPage = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("select[id^=page]"));
    // ...
} catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
    // no pages found
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Your code almost helped. But I'm not yet able to use the nextPage value to select a dropdown value. I'm trying to use this code

`existpage = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("select[id^=page]"));
     String nextPageID = Integer.toString(Integer.parseInt(existpage.getAttribute("id")) + 1);
     Select nextPage = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("page" + nextPageID))); 
new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("nextPage"))).selectByVisibleText("ASJD");`

This is not working either:
`nextPage.selectByVisibleText("ASJD");`
How should I use the nextPage variable there?

Comment: @RahulBaskaran `nextPage` is a select instance, you should be able to use it this way `nextPage.selectByVisibleText("ASJD");`. What are the symptoms, any errors? Thanks!

Comment: I'm getting the below error after reaching this line
`Select nextPage = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("page" + nextPageID)));`

Error
`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "page3"
 at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
 at automationFramework.AutoBPS.main(AutoBPS.java:43)`

Comment: These are the lines after that `Select` statement:

`driver.findElement(By.id("addPage")).click();
 nextPage.selectByVisibleText("Benefit Finance -> Payments");`

Answer (score 2):

I would try doing something along the lines of the following, assuming that you will have no other drop down elements present in the page (which I assume from your question is the case).

```
try {
driver.findElement(By.tagName("select"))
} catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
//create first dropdown
}
```

You could try and fill an array with the id of every select element on the  page and search for presence of one which matches the pattern "page\d" and go from there.

Comment: Actually there are a few more drop-down present in the page.. All not related to this functionality though. And I don't want to log any information. I need to automatically select the value in the next dropdown if the previous one already exists.

Comment: Do your drop-downs for this functionality have a naming convention that you can use to check for their presence? Anything that lets you write an xpath unique to this type of drop-down in your app/page?

Comment: `isDisplayed()` call is actually not needed here, `NoSuchElementException` would be thrown by `findElement` if no element would be found.